# how to execute a query like this one?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following columns in SQL Server 2008 table `t_list`:
`firstid, firstpoints, secondid, secondpoints`

I want to select all of those columns in an SQL query but order in a specific way.

I want to select the top 400 of those columns, ordering by `firstpoints` only for the `firstid` column, and `secondpoints` only for the `secondid` column in one query, for example:

```
SELECT TOP 400 firstid, firstpoints 
FROM t_list 
ORDER BY firstpoints desc
```

and

```
select top 400 secondid, secondpoints 
FROM t_list 
ORDER BY secondpoints desc
```

How can I fit the two above queries into one query, returning output like

```
firstid, firstpoints, secondid, secondpoints

1. firstidresult, firstpointresult, secondidresult, secondpointsresult
2. etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on MS SQL Server

```
Select t1.FirstID, t1.FirstPoints, t2.SecondID, t2.SecondPoints
From (Select Top 400 row_number() Over (Order By FirstPoints desc) As r, FirstID, FirstPoints From t_list) As t1
    Join (Select Top 400 row_number() Over (Order By SecondPoints desc) As r, SecondID, SecondPoints From t_list) as t2 on t1.r = t2.r
```

Hope I understood your problem correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 400 FirstId
        ,FirstPoints
    FROM t_list
    ORDER BY FirstPoints
    ) f

UNION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 400 SecondId
        ,SecondPoints
    FROM t_list
    ORDER BY SecondPoints
    ) s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE1 AS 
(SELECT 1 as [Order],
    firstid, 
    firstpoints,
    Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY firstpoints desc ) as RowNum
FROM t_list 
),
CTE2 AS 
(SELECT 
    2,
    secondid, 
    secondpoints,
    Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY secondpoints) as RowNum
FROM t_list 
)
SELECT [Order],
    firstid as Id, 
    firstpoints  as Points
FROM CTE1
WHERE RowNum <= 400
UNION 
SELECT [Order],
     secondid, 
     secondpoints 
FROM CTE2
WHERE RowNum <= 400
ORDER BY [Order], RowNum
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to combine your two filters into one table using 'UNION ALL'

(SELECT TOP 400 firstid, firstpoints 
FROM t_list
ORDER BY firstpoints desc)

UNION ALL

(select top 400 secondid, secondpoints
FROM t_list
ORDER BY secondpoints desc )